# Showing All views in the top corner in genymotion Emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation, genymotion

I have recently installed Android Studio with genymotion emulator based on a youtube tutorial. I'm designing a simple calculator with only one button and two Number(EditText) views . When designing, it is showing different views at different positions.But, when I run it, in the emulator, all the views are appearing in the top corner. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can we guess your code? *If so, we'd sell your code.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the ConstraintLayout from Android Studio, and you are missing the constraints for your layout.

To fix, go inside the Layout Editor, and click on the infer constraints button (https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#use-autoconnect-and-infer-constraints) , recompile and deploy to your device and the buttons should be in the correct spot.

I'll also note, you should try the official Android Emulator: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html